# If the value in one dropdown changed, how to reload the values for the second dropdown? How to do Partial Reload in InertiaJs

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

### Q: If the value in one dropdown changed, how to reload the values for the second dropdown?

When user change the **`category`** dropdown, then I want to show the **`subcategory`** in the dropdown

**Frontend:** `VueJs (v3)` 
**Server Side Rendering:** `IneratiaJs` 
**Backend:** `Laravel (v9)`

**VueComponent**

```vue
 const props = defineProps({
  errors: Object,
  categories: Object,
  subcategories: Object,
})

const form = useForm({
    category_id: '',
    subcategory_id: '',
    name: '',
    price: '',
    discount: '',
    image: 'sample',
    description: ''
});


let getSubcategory = (event) => {
    
    if(event.target.value !== "") {

       Inertia.reload({   
                'category_id': event.target.value 
            },
            {   only: ['subcategories'],
                onSuccess: page => {
                    alert();
                    console.log('onSuccess');
                    console.log(props.categories);
                    console.log(props.subcategories);
                    console.log(page);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

const submit = () => {
    form.post(route('store.subcategory'), {
        onFinish: () => form.reset(),
    });
};
```

**Vue Template**

```vue
<template>
    <Head title="Add Product" />

    <BreezeAuthenticatedLayout>
        <template #header>
           
                <form @submit.prevent="submit">
                   <div class="mt-4">
                        <BreezeLabel for="category_id" value="Category Name" />
                        <select @change="getSubcategory" v-model="form.category_id"  id="category_id" class="block mt-1 w-full">
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            <option  v-for="category in categories"  :value="category.id">{{ category.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                        <div v-if="errors.category_id" class="text-red-400">
                            {{ errors.category_id }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                         <BreezeLabel for="subcategory_id" value="Subcategory Name" />
                        <select v-model="form.subcategory_id" id="subcategory_id" class="block mt-1 w-full">
                            <option value="">Select Sategory</option>
                            <option  v-for="subcategory in subcategories"  :value="subcategory.id">{{ subcategory.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                        <div v-if="errors.subcategory_id" class="text-red-400">
                            {{ errors.subcategory_id }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
 </BreezeAuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

**Laravel Route:** **`routes/web.php`**

```php
Route::get('/create/product/{category_id?}', [ProductController::class, 'create'])->name('create.product'); //Form: Create Product
```

**Product Controller:** **`ProductController.php`**

```php
public function create($category_id = null)
    {        
        return Inertia::render('Product/Create', [          
            //I want Evaluated immediately on Page Load.
            'categories' =>  $categories = Category::all(),

            //Want Lazy load here.
            'subcategories' => function(){                            
                if(!empty($category_id)){
                    $category = Category::find($category_id); 
                    $subcategories = $category->subcategories()->get();
                }
            },
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing **`Create method`** in **Product Controller** and **`script setup`** it's working

```php
public function create($category_id = null)
    {       
        return Inertia::render('Product/Create', [

            // ALWAYS included on first visit - OPTIONALLY included on partial reloads - ALWAYS evaluated            
            'categories' => Category::has('subcategories')->get(),

            // NEVER included on first visit - OPTIONALLY included on partial reloads - ONLY evaluated when needed
            'subcategories' => Inertia::lazy(fn () =>              
                Subcategory::with('category')->where('category_id', '=', $category_id)->get()                    
            ),
        ]);
    }
```

**Vue SCRIPT:** I was sending wrong **parameters.** Then I saw correct way of [partial relaod](https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads#making-partial-visits) on official site

```vue
let getSubcategory = (event) => {    
    if(event.target.value !== "") {
       Inertia.visit(
            route('create.product', { 
                category_id: event.target.value
            }),{ 
                only: ['subcategories'],
                preserveState: true,
                preserveScroll: true,
            }
        );
    }
}
```